# Bio-signal discontinuity after FIR filtering

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I'm filtering respiration signal. I have a signal of duration equal to 10 minutes, so I decided to divided it into period of 10 s. I filtered each epoch with FIR filter, but I have discontinuities each 10s.
I attached an example.
I can not filter all the signal at once by the theory, so how can avoid discontinuity?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain the filter state. For an FIR filter that's fairly easy since the state are just the last $N-1$ samples if your previous input, where $N$ is the FIR filter length.

Most filter functions have a built in option for doing this. If you don't have it just do the following:

1. Prepend you current frame with the $N-1$ last samples of the previous frame
2. Run the filter
3. Throw away the first $N-1$ samples of the output.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar, but the problem remains. I follow your tips and do it manually,  but I still see discontinuity. Maybe I wrong in some way, do you know any function that do it?

Comment: Maltlabs `filter()` or Python's `lfilter()` have options to preserve state across frames. What language are you using ?